# Vue Plugin Development - Importing SCSS Globally

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs3

I'm working on a Vue Plugin and I'm trying to import and use a SCSS file (which in turn contains a bunch of other SCSS imports inside). So I'd ideally want to import and inject the SCSS file globally for the plugin.

I've tried the following methods (and they don't work):

##### 1. Using `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: `@import "@/assets/scss/main.scss";`,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

This method does not bundle the styles when the plugin is built. None of the stylings are preserved on the build.

##### 2. Just importing it in the plugin module

```
import MyComponent from "./plugin/MyComponent.vue";
import "./assets/main.scss"; // Tried it here

export default {
    install: (app: any): void => {
        require("./assets/main.scss"); // And here as well
        app.component("my-component", MyComponent);
    },
};
```

This approach doesn't work as well, even during direct plugin injection while development.

##### 3. Importing in Plugin Components

I imported the SCSS file in every individual component that's being used in the plugin. For example in `MyComponent.vue`, I can use:

```
<template>...</template>
<style>
@import "../assets/main.scss";
</style>
```

In this case also it didn't work.

What is the right way of importing a SCSS file globally and making it work in a plugin?

### Edit:

In the installed plugin, I can see that there's a CSS file packaged, but I'm not sure why it's not being applied. The class names are also there with all font imports and stuff. But it's not being applied.

Comment: do you have a global.scss file? i think that's all we had to do on our vue project... when we switched to nuxt we added it to the nuxt config as css: ["@/assets/css/global.scss"],

Comment: i'm not sure if it's possible but regardless, you might be better of asking users to import it themselves so they can create their own stylesheet if they want to. well-known components like Vuetify, Bootstrap Vue, and Vue-Select does it.

Comment: Yes, I have a `main.scss` file that I'm importing. I see that the file is being packaged when I'm installing the plugin, but the CSS in it is not being applied for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `extract: false` to `css` in `vue.config.js`. This one line thing cost me 14 hours to figure out, I hope nobody else has to go through this mess again. Here's the full configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: `@import "@/assets/scss/main.scss";`,
            },
        },
        extract: false,
    },
};
```

This will also take care of SCSS variables, mixins, etc. The plugin will not come with a separate CSS file with it, everything will be included in the bundled `js` files.